# display: box, in what kind of elements those works?

Tags: css

I have this .html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML5 App</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom.css"> 
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
    <div id="top">Top</div>
    <div id="middle">
        <div id="left">Left</div>
        <div id="center">
            Center
            <img src="iconos/Android MNMLcony.png" class="item" >
            <img src="iconos/Android MNMLcony.png" class="item" >
        </div>
        <div id="right">Right</div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom">Bottom</div>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

and this css

```
html, body { margin: 0; height: 100%; }

#container {
    height: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box; /* like LinearLayout */
    display:    -moz-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical; /* like android:orientation */
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
}

#top, #bottom { height: 50px; background-color: #A8A8A8}

#middle {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1; /* like android:layout_weight */
    -moz-box-flex: 1;

    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
}

#left, #right { background-color: #d0d0d0; -webkit-box-flex:1; }

#center {
background-color: #D8D8D8;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
}
```

I show this web

http://img839.imageshack.us/img839/4485/capturadepantalla201305q.png

I want elements in  (like text "Center" and the two images) to show like those

http://img811.imageshack.us/img811/4451/capturadepantalla201305g.png

I have try to add those in css #center

```
#center {
background-color: #D8D8D8;
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
   -moz-box-flex: 1;

display: -webkit-box;
display:    -moz-box;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
   -moz-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

...but i see my page like my first image...

I don't know why "display: box; -webkit-box-orient: vertical" works fine if childs of the tags are "div" but not if they are texts, img, etc..

Any idea?

Comment: Do a new `div` for each image in your `center` content and use `<div style="clear:both">`. Hope that works

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mZ82A/) example

Comment: Thanks! it's work but i want to know if it's possible in some way to do that without adding more divs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some `br` if you dont want to add more `divs`  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mZ82A/2/)

```
<div id="center">
        Center<br />
        <img src="iconos/Android MNMLcony.png" class="item" ><br />
        <img src="iconos/Android MNMLcony.png" class="item" ><br />
</div>
```

But this should be the best option: (with some divs)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mZ82A/)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried enclosing each image in a div?

```
    <div id="center">
        Center
        <div><img src="iconos/Android MNMLcony.png" class="item" ></div>
        <div><img src="iconos/Android MNMLcony.png" class="item" ></div>
    </div>
```

I apologize if I misunderstood your need.

Comment: Don't worry! you have understood me! Yes, if i enclosing each image in a div it's work! But i want to know if it's possible in some way to do that without adding more divs...